# Python files are given extension '.py?' instead of '.py'

Tags: python, macos, curl, terminal, mv

I am trying to make a script that will download a file (a python file in this case). The file is then renamed to whatever is contained on the first line the said file. The files appear to be named properly in the gui file system but terminal reveals they are infact named with a .py? extension instead of .py. The problem is '.py?' files do not execute when 'python file.py?' is entered. So here is roughly what is going on in pseudo code:

```
curl fileurl.com -o temp             #Downloads file to working directory with name 'temp'
file_name = getFirstLineOf(temp)     #Returns the first line of the file to variable 'file_name'
runInTerminal('mv temp '+file_name)  #renames file 'temp' as 'file_name'
```

Getting more specific...

```
file_name = 'aFile.py'               #assume name came from first line of said file
runInTerminal('mv temp '+file_name)
```

...Results in the file being given the name 'aFile.py?' instead of 'aFile.py'

Comment: The `?` might not indicate that there is a question mark in the filename, it might indicate that there is an unprintable character in the filename.

Comment: Try printing out the actual bytes of `file_name` (if that first sample is meant to be Python, `print(repr(file_name))` and you'll see whether there are any unprintable characters.

Comment: Also, you actually _can_ run a file named `aFile.py?` from the shell, if that's it's actual name. You just need to escape it or quote it so the shell won't try to interpret it: `python 'aFile.py?'`

Comment: Try also `ls -b` on the command line to print out the file name with unprintable characters replaced by C-style escapes.